# $(ItemPath) returning the wrong path

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've just upgraded to VS 2012 and I have an external tool command in which I'm using the $(ItemPath) variable.  If the current document is in the solution the variable returns the path of that document.  But if the document isn't in the solution it's returning the path of the document in the next tab.

Does anyone know if this is expected behaviour, or is there a setting I need to change somewhere?

In VS 2010 this command works as I would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I will send feedback via that forum.

Comment: This is fixed in Visual Studio 2012 Update 5.